# Rest DSL restConfiguration way to dynamically inject Jetty port from jetty.xml

Tags: rest, apache-camel, jetty, dsl

can you dynamically inject the port set in the jetty.xml config file? 
I have multiple jboss fuse containers running, each has a different configuration of ports from rmiRegistryPort, to jetty.port. I would like to be able to just inject the port value from the jetty.xml.  if i am using camel-jetty, do I need to worry about setting the port as it automatically takes if from this file???

```
        restConfiguration() 
            .component("jetty")         
            .host("localhost")          
            .port(getPort())            
            .scheme("https")            
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)  
            .jsonDataFormat("json-jackson")     
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know myself, but the [Camel REST DSL Docs](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html) say:

> if you use servlet component then the port number configured here does not apply, as the port number in use is the actual port number the servlet component is using, e.g., if using Apache Tomcat its the tomcat HTTP port, if using Apache Karaf it's the HTTP service in Karaf that uses port 8181 by default etc. Though in those situations setting the port number here, allows tooling and JMX to know the port number, so its recommended to set the port number to the number that the servlet engine uses.

Based on this description I **assume** that:

- Camel uses the actual jetty HTTP endpoint
- Whatever port you set in the `restConfiguration` it is ignored for the jetty HTTP endpoint
- JMX and other tools only work correct if you set the correct port in the `restConfiguration`
- You have to provide the correct jetty port for the `restConfiguration` (no auto-magic)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the port value inside an application.properties and read it to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Victor, yeah, ... I was just wondering if there is some magic under the covers with the Jetty server, I will need to test this out I guess. 
since there is a jetty.xml config file under etc/jetty.xml that defines the jetty config... but in every example I see the defining of a port ... it looks like it is possible if enabled ??? but I don't know. reason is I have 8 different JBoss Fuse containers running all having different etc/configs to keep from port conflicts.

```
inside jetty.xml
        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <!-- Special server connectors -->
        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <!-- This is a sample for alternative connectors, enable if needed -->
        <!-- =========================================================== -->
        <!--
        <Call name="addConnector">
                <Arg>
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                                <Arg name="server">
                                        <Ref refid="Server" />
                                </Arg>
                                <Arg name="factories">
                                        <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
                                                <Item>
                                                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                                                                <Arg name="config">
                                                                        <Ref refid="httpConfig" />
                                                                </Arg>
                                                        </New>
                                                </Item>
                                        </Array>
                                </Arg>
                                <Set name="host">
                                        <Property name="jetty.host" default="localhost" />
                                </Set>
                                <Set name="port">
                                        <Property name="jetty.port" default="8285" />
                                </Set>
                                <Set name="idleTimeout">
                                        <Property name="http.timeout" default="30000" />
                                </Set>
                                <Set name="name">jettyConn1</Set>
                        </New>
                </Arg>
        </Call>
```